# Relative path for cartridges in demandware

Tags: demandware

I am working on Demandware business manager where i need to change the site settings.

Going to Manage Sites> Selecting a site and going to settings,

there is a field called Cartridges where i put up a list of cartridges to be deployed for this site.

I want to add these cartridges to a different hierarchy like inside a folder.
Is there a way to define this in the Cartridges field under settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot add cartridges into subfolders. Cartridges need to reside directly in the *version directory* on the server.

Comment: Is there any other way to run two different sites with different set of cartridges?

Comment: You can simply assign different cartridges to the different sites. Cartridges are not deployed to sites but globally so you can have Site 1 - Cartridge1:Cartridge3 and Sites 2 - Cartridge2:Cartridge3 with Cartridge1-3 being the 3 uploaded cartridges.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can have hierarchy folder structure IN YOUR LOCAL MACHINE (or GIT/SVN) but they will be uploaded to the DW WebDAV at the same level.

For example, in your machine, you will have:

- Catridge1

  - Cartridge1.1
  - Cartridge1.2
- Catridge2

When you "Import" cartridges into Eclipse, don't forget to select "Nested-folders"

When Eclipse build the cartridges into webdav it should be:

- Catridge1
- Cartridge1.1
- Cartridge1.2
- Catridge2

Answer (score 0):

Cartridges - is a separate units (entities) and can be fully independence in workaround with full of logic and UI features. Off course, you can develop additional cartridge for your site, for example, if you need to extend your current payment systems, or you need some multi usable cartridge and you plane sell your cartridge as a, kind of plugin.

In other case, if need extend only locally feature - no needs reason to deploy new brand cartridge.

But each of cartridges you can upload to sendbox only separately. Else, if you nested 'physically' folder with different cartridge, you'll broke it all.

Hope it will help you. Please, specify in comment your issue, if I understand this quote not quite well.